# Can't get company-dabbrv mode to work

Tags: company-mode, completion

I think I've setup company mode correctly, yet I can't get company-dabbrv to work as default. I can launch it manually with `company-dabbrv`, but it won't auto-suggest completions in a buffer.

This is the output of `company-diag`:

```
Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) of 2016-12-17 on foutrelis
Company 0.9.2

company-backends: (company-abbrev company-ispell company-bbdb company-nxml company-css company-eclim company-semantic company-clang company-xcode company-cmake company-capf company-files
        (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
        company-oddmuse company-dabbrev)

Used backend: company-abbrev
Prefix: ""
Completions:
  "wokr"
  "willbe"
  "vulnerible"
  "tkaes"
  "tjhe"
  "specifc"
  "similiar"
  "sepcific"
  "relize"
  "propertiers"
  "proffesors
   ... (this goes on...)
```

So it seems to me dabbrv mode is loaded.

This is my config:

```
  (use-package company 
   :ensure t
   :config
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)

  (setq company-idle-delay 0)
  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2) 


 (defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
       '((company-capf company-files company-dabbrv))))


   (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-mode-hook)
   )
```

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: that is not how you setup buffer local `company-backend`. See [here](https://github.com/CSRaghunandan/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-rust.el#L27) as an example of how you can define it.

Comment: thx @ChakravarthyRaghunandan. i changed the code to this ``` (defun my-org-mode-hook ()
      (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
           '((company-capf company-files company-dabbrv))))``` yet it still dosent seem to work. is the above code correct? am i missing something?

Comment: have you added the function you defined to `org-mode-hook` ?

Comment: thx @ChakravarthyRaghunandan. yes ive added `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-mode-hook)` and it still isnt working

Comment: Can you please update the post to indicate what you've tried so far after my suggestion? It should work, I see no reason as to why it wouldn't. Setting up `company` can be so confusing for beginners. I faced the same issue when I started out using `company`

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan, updated the post as you suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51573/discussion-between-chakravarthy-raghunandan-and-zeltak).

Comment: Did you manage to get this going? I have dabbrev in the global set and it doesn't work.